# проблема с -nan(ind)

Tags: c++

Не могу понять, почему пишет -nan(ind) в ответе

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
#define x 1.6 
#define h 1.6 
void main()
{
    double f, e;
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);
    f = log(3 * x) - h; 
    e = pow(pow(f,3), 1 / 5.0); 
    printf("f=%f\t\te=%e\n", f, e);
    printf("h=%f\t\tx=%e\n", x, h);
```

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow

Comment: Что мне надо поменять в коде, что бы e = числу, а не -nan(ind)

Comment: ¿Рассчитываете получить число возводя отрицательно число в дробную степень? Такая операция не определена. Попробуйте `h` уменьшить, чтобы число оставалось положительным. ¿Там случаем не опечатка - почему у `h` такое же значение, как и у `x`?

Comment: Понял, спасибо!

Comment: @user7860670 то есть, Вы хотите сказать, что кубический корень с отрицательного числа нельзя получить?

Comment: @KoVadim Нельзя: `If base is finite and negative and exp is finite and non-integer, a domain error occurs and a range error may occur.`

Comment: У меня есть вот такое уравнение https://imgur.com/a/66kJZcj и у меня не получается его сделать кодом, то есть у меня е выходит -nan(ind)

Comment: @user7860670 этого не может функция с cmath, но это не значит, что этого нельзя сделать

Comment: @KoVadim но это будет уже совсем другая история. Ну и я подозреваю, что в само задание закралась опечатка.

Comment: @user7860670 https://imgur.com/a/66kJZcj вот задание

Comment: да, там f получается немножко меньше нуля. но при этом обычный калькулятор прекрасно вычисляет значение выражения. Что делать? подойдти с этим к преподавателю. Возможно, он поменяет немного входные данные. Или просто взять и сделать нормальное вычисление корня с отрицательного числа. Это не сложно